# If a user asks a good question with a bad title, should we help them or close the question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, new-users, close-reasons

I was answering a question by a 250-rep user who wanted to know how the performance of serializing an object to a local JSON representation compared to persisting the object to a MySQL database.  It was closed in less than three minutes, and I ended up having to post my answer in the comments.

The problem is that the title of the question was "Which is faster : writing / reading JSON text file vs query a MySQL database?".  Clearly, the title is awful.  However, if someone took the time to read the question, it becomes clear what the OP was actually asking.

My initial perspective is that closing this kind of question would be discouraging to several subsets of SO users (new users who aren't yet experienced with asking questions on SO, international users who are more competent in their programming language and/or in verbal communication than in written English).  However, it's possible that I'm completely misunderstanding the objective.

So, my question is, which is more in line with the goals of the SO community :

**(A)** to provide an environment where all developers can get helpful information and offer constructive guidance to help them assimilate when necessary,

or

**(B)** to provide a helpful environment for a select social and professional tier of developers and blacklist them who don't talk no good?

Comment: There is an edit facility on all sites.

Comment: @Lucifer, funny name.  The question was closed within three minutes.  That doesn't really give time to edit

Comment: you can edit and flag to moderator for request to open it again

Comment: @smartcaveman: You are aware that closed questions can still be edited and reopened?

Comment: Also, irony has it that your own question is the prime example of your question. The title asks something meaningful, but the question turns toward the end nearly into a rant.

Comment: @GardenGnobobby, :-D

Comment: To be clear, the question you refer to had *both* a horrible title and awful content. There was absolutely no way to deduce what the OP meant before he changed the title--and that was *after* the question [had already been closed](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10911045/revisions).

Comment: @Juhana, then why was I able to answer it correctly prior to clarification?

Comment: You didn't. The OP meant saving the JSON as text files, you talked about "storing it in memory".

Comment: @Juhana, Memory != RAM - I can't imagine that you are implying that not specifying clearly enough whether you intend to store data on disk or in an active memory cache is sufficient reason to close.

Answer (score 11):

Use the edit link to improve the title - and anything else that's wrong with the post.

Even if the post is closed - or perhaps I should say, especially if the post is closed - you should edit the post to improve it.

If the post is closed you should:

1. Vote to reopen - if you have 3,000 reputation or more.
2. Link to the question in an appropriate chat room to get some more eyes on the post so other 3,000+ reputation users can take a look and case reopen votes.
3. Possibly raise a post here on Meta for the same purpose. When Stack Overflow gets its own site specific meta this will be more useful. At the moment it could be drowned out with all the network wide questions that appear here.
4. Possibly flag it for moderator attention if you don't think it's going to get the attention  required to reopen it. Only do this if you have made significant edits to the post.

Comment: I disagree mostly with point 2. While I agree that there should be some sort of mechanism to get more eyes onto a question for that, I disagree that this should be Meta. Chat might be better suited.

Comment: @GardenGnobobby - good point. I've updated the answer.